# how to avoid join and convenient extend

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

i have three table 
one is busStation
other is busLine
busLine contains many bustations,
i want to use hibernate to mapping join,but my boss let my use 
busStation_to_busLine table to associate with the two tables.
he say the way is convenient for convert to hbase(at present we use mysql).
so i have to select busStation,and select busStation_to_busLine,and select busLine,to get what i want.
how could let my code simpler not to select three tables,and not suffer from the hibernate join problem.
so what dao framework should i use,or how to let my code easier to write?or design better table structure?

**update**
it report exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: java.util.List, at table: bus_station, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(busLines)]

my entity and table is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bus_line")
@NamedQuery(name="BusLine.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM BusLine b")
public class BusLine implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long firstExpressTime;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long lastExpressTime;

    private Integer lineDirection;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=10)
    private String lineName;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long originatingStationID;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=10)
    private String originatingStationName;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Long terminusID;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=10)
    private String terminusName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="busLines")
    private List<BusStation> busStations = new ArrayList<BusStation>();
    omit getter and setter method
}

@Entity
@Table(name="bus_station")
@NamedQuery(name="BusStation.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM BusStation b")
public class BusStation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Double stationLat;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Double stationLng;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=20)
    private String stationName;

    @JoinTable(name="bus_line_to_station",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="stationID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="lineID"))
    private List<BusLine> busLines = new ArrayList<BusLine>();

    omit setter and getter method
}

   CREATE TABLE `bus_line` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `lineName` varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
  `originatingStationName` varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
  `originatingStationID` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  `terminusID` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  `terminusName` varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
  `firstExpressTime` datetime NOT NULL ,
  `lastExpressTime` datetime NOT NULL ,
  `lineDirection` int(3) DEFAULT '1' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `bus_line_to_station` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `lineID` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  `stationID` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  `stationOrder` int(3) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `bus_station` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `stationName` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
  `stationLng` double NOT NULL ,
  `stationLat` double NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You do have entities on tables `busStation` and `busLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ManyToMany` to map the relation between `BusStation` and `BusLine`

```
@Entity
public class BusStation {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "busStation_to_busLine", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "busStation_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "busLine_id")
    private List<BusLine> busLines = new ArrayList<BusLine>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class BusLine {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "busLines")
    private List<BusStation> busStations = new ArrayList<BusStation>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks,but it report exception Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: bus_station, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(busLines)]

Comment: @user2245634 In your code, you are missing `@ManyToMany` on `busLines` field